# Talend DB connections

Tags: database, connection-string, talend

I guess I don't yet understand Talend Open Studio and how connections are setup. I've got a couple setup in Metadata --> Db Connections. When I drop something like a tMSSqlInput control onto a form, there's a checkbox for "Use an existing connection" but I have nothing available in that Component List dropdown or anywhere else.

TIA,
Ken

Comment: FIrst, drag and drop the connection you created onto the designer, and choose a tMSSqlConnection in the list. Then add a tMSSqlInput and link it to tMSSqlConnection using an OnSubjobOk trigger. Now, when you check use exisiting connection in tMSSqlInput, you will be able to select  tMSSqlConnection from the list and use it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Guess it's a similar process when moving that data as output to another source.